# Display XY after Button Click

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript

I am creating a map that will generate an XY coordinate based off the location that a user clicks.  I only want this location to be generated after the user clicks a button to enable the draw toolbar and then clicks the map.  The coordinate will be passed to another web page and ultimately stored in a database so I need to make sure that a point can't accidentally be created.  Code below as well as a link to what I currently have running.

I may be wrong but I think it should have something to with a dojo.connect but I may be wrong.  But you can see the commented out options that I have tried.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no"/>
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Maps Toolbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      djConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.2"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("esri.map");
      dojo.require("dijit.Toolbar");
      dojo.require("esri.toolbars.draw");
      dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // optimize: load dijit layer
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");


      var map, toolbar, symbol, geomTask;
      var gsvc = null;
      var pt = null;

      function init() {
        var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-11721159.665358918,"ymin":-11721159.665358918,"xmax":8277212.918942982,"ymax":9858297.322750043,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
        map = new esri.Map("map",{extent:startExtent});
        dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", createToolbar);
        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);

        gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

      }



      function createToolbar(map) {

        toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
        //set drawing mode to extent
        //toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
        dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);
        //dojo.connect(map, "onClick", projectToLatLong);

      }

      function addToMap(geometry) {
      map.graphics.clear();
      //toolbar.deactivate();
      map.showZoomSlider();
       switch (geometry.type) {
          case "point":
            var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND);

        }

        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
        //dojo.connect(map, "onUpdateEnd(geometry)", projectToLatLong);


      }

      function projectToLatLong(evt) {

        var point = evt.mapPoint;
        var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326});


        gsvc.project([ point ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {

         pt = projectedPoints[0];
          //display list of points in extent
          dojo.byId("results").innerHTML = "&nbsp;Latitude = " + pt.y + ",&nbsp;Longitude = " + pt.x;

        });
      }

      dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div id="mainWindow" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false" style="width:100%; height:90%;">
    <div id="header" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" style="height:75px;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#400D12;overflow:hidden;">
      <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="projectToLatLong(evt); toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);">Show XY</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="border:solid 2px #587498;margin:5px;" region="center">
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- list points in extent -->
    <div id="results" style="width:50%; height:20px; border:1px solid #000; overflow:auto;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://geoville.org/viewers/XY/

Thanks for your help.

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if there is a reason, but I don't see the reason to use dojo.connect to call the projectToLatLong function.  Just call the function directly, and pass in the geometry.  I made two tiny changes and it worked for me:

```
enter code here
```

Maps Toolbar
    
    
      html, body {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
      }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  djConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("esri.map");
  dojo.require("dijit.Toolbar");
  dojo.require("esri.toolbars.draw");
  dojo.require("dijit.dijit"); // optimize: load dijit layer
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
  dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");


  var map, toolbar, symbol, geomTask;
  var gsvc = null;
  var pt = null;

  function init() {
    var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-11721159.665358918,"ymin":-11721159.665358918,"xmax":8277212.918942982,"ymax":9858297.322750043,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
    map = new esri.Map("map",{extent:startExtent});
    dojo.connect(map, "onLoad", createToolbar);
    var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
    map.addLayer(basemap);

    gsvc = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

  }



  function createToolbar(map) {

    toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
    //set drawing mode to extent
    //toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
    dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);
    //dojo.connect(map, "onClick", projectToLatLong);

  }

  function addToMap(geometry) {
  map.graphics.clear();

  //toolbar.deactivate();
  map.showZoomSlider();
   switch (geometry.type) {
      case "point":
        var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND);
       break;
    }

    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geometry, symbol);
    map.graphics.add(graphic);
    //dojo.connect(map, "onUpdateEnd(geometry)", projectToLatLong);
    projectToLatLong(geometry);

  }

  function projectToLatLong(evt) {
    var point = evt;
    var outSR = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326});


    gsvc.project([ point ], outSR, function(projectedPoints) {

     pt = projectedPoints[0];
      //display list of points in extent
      dojo.byId("results").innerHTML = "&nbsp;Latitude = " + pt.y + ",&nbsp;Longitude = " + pt.x;

    });
  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
```

Show XY

Comment: Thanks badkins!  That works exactly as desired.  No specific reason for using dojo.connect other than I am still learning.  Now I know how to call a function from within another function.

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes you will need to use dojo.connect, for instance when you need to wait for something to complete - such as a query - before moving onto the function.  But in this case it is already ensured that your map click query is complete because of this line: dojo.connect(toolbar, "onDrawEnd", addToMap);